# JavaScript Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript

I'm writing this code to try and simulate an electronic circuit. It is producing this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`. I have counted the curly braces and the normal braces, and they all seem to be lined up right. My code:

```
var grid = new Array(5);
for (i=0; i <5; i++) {
  grid[i]=new Array(5);
}

grid[1][1]=2;
grid[1][2]=1;
grid[1][3]=1;
grid[2][3]=1;
grid[3][3]=1;
grid[3][2]=1;
grid[3][1]=3;
grid[3][0]=2;
grid[4][1]=1;
var time=100;
for (var i=0;i<time;i++) {
  for (var x=0; x<grid[0].length) {
    for (var y=0; y<grid.length;y++) {
      if (grid[x][y]==2) {
        if (grid[x+1][y]=1) {
          grid[x+1][y]=2;
        }

        if (grid[x-1][y]=1) {
          grid[x-1][y]=2;
        }

        if (grid[x][y+1]=1) {
          grid[x][y+1]=2;
        }

        if (grid[x][y-1]=1) {
          grid[x][y-1]=2;
        }
      }

      if (grid[x][y]==3) {
        if (grid[x][y+1] == grid[x][y-1] && grid[x][y+1]==2) {
          grid[x+1][y]=2;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

for (var x=0;x<6;x++) {
  for (var y=0;y<6;y++) {
    alert(grid[x][y]);
  }
}
```

Why is this happening? I'm sorry if there is an easy explanation, my IDE doesn't give me the line it happens on. But I'm almost sure it has nothing to do with the number of braces not being lines up.

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic, but what IDE are you using?

Comment: It's not causing the syntax error, but you also have a lot of what looks like assignments where you probably meant to have comparisons, `=` instead of `==` or `===`.

Comment: This question should be closed, not answered

Comment: If you hover over the close button there are 3 possible reasons given: 1) shows no research effort, 2) unclear, or 3) useless, and I believe 2 out of 3 apply to this question -- you could have done more research on your error -- and this question is useless, it's a simple typo, and is not going to help any future users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop on line `19` has a *SyntaxError*, `expr3` is missing

```
for (var x=0; x<grid[0].length; expr3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon on your 3rd for loop:

```
for (var x=0; x<grid[0].length)
```